# Is it a good practice to use a function call inside a function?

Tags: c

I have a very large C program for Molecular dynamics. It works correctly with N=10000 particles.  When I increase the particles to N=100000 by increasing the variable size, it generated a segmentation fault.

I executed `ulimit -s unlimited` and problem was resolved.

**Q1.**
Is any way to check how much stack memory my code is going to use, performance check of the code(optimization), memory leakage.

**Q2.**
If the structure of my code is like, nested functions,

```
int main() {
    function1();
    return 0;
}

void function1() {
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
        function2();
    }
}

void function2() { 
    double Var[100000];
}
```

Will the use of `function2()` inside a for loop use more stack memory than executing it only one time?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this exact code to have significantly different memory requirements with / without the for loop (perhaps one `int`)... Recursion will cause you problems. You could try using `valgrind` or some memory analysis to get some visibility on what's happening.

Comment: The problem is ***not*** the nested function. The problem is that you allocate large arrays on the stack. `double Var[100000];` should be `double *Var = malloc(100000 * sizeof(double));` Of course, you'll need to `free` the memory when it's no longer needed.

Comment: There is no particular reason why it should use more stack memory just because it is called from a `for` loop unless you are "parallelizing" the code (e.g. with OpenMP).

Comment: Usually your compiler will inline short function on usual optimisation levels if it sees the functions body (independent of marking them inline). In -O3 it will inline nearly everything it sees.

Comment: You can't make a function call except from within a function, so the answer to the headline question is "yes: it is not only good practice; it is unavoidable".  But your main question is about stack memory usage.  You'll need to use dynamically allocated memory (`malloc()` et al) as your problem size gets bigger.  Stack is a limited resource; the default is typically about 1 MiB on Windows and 8 MiB on Unix-like systems.  Don't allocate megabytes of memory on the stack as in your `function2()`.

Comment: The main issue with memory would be if you were recursively calling a function from within itself given the use case you outlined.  So, if you called function2() and it called itself 100,000 times then your stack usage would increase.  That isn't the case with the code you presented.

Comment: @user6556709: I reread the question and edited my comment. However, it did once include "If all the functions are 2-5 lines each, then you end up with incomprehensible code". I'm a strong advocate of small functions, but I mean 5-20 lines rather than 2-5 lines typically. (I work on a code base where functions are routinely several hundred lines long, or more. It annoys me, but can't easily be fixed.) Yes, naming can help, but there comes a point at which the necessary paragraph of name becomes counter-productive. It's a balance. It depends on context. More small functions are usually better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, then I've misunderstood you. 5-20 is good a range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1. I want to know if there is any way to check how much stack memory my code is going to use, performance check of the code(optimization), memory leakage.

Not really. The C standard does not even mention the stack, and any C compiler can create binaries that does not use the stack and still conform to the C standard.

However, in reality a stack is almost always used and the overhead is very small. Just sum up all the local variables and you will get a good estimate.

Performance should not be predicted. It should be measured, and then you optimize if necessary.

It's very hard, if not impossible, for a compiler to detect memory leaks in a reliable way. You can use programs like Valgrind for that.

> Q2. if the structure of my code is like,nested functions,
>   because of the function2 call inside a for loop is it going to use more stack memory than using once only?

No. Each time `function2()` is called, a new stackframe is created with enough space for 100000 doubles. But it will be released immediately when the function returns. The problem here is not calling a function in a loop. The problem is that you're allocating HUGE arrays on the stack, which might become a problem. You should consider allocating them dynamically instead. Basically, it will look like this:

```
void function2
{
    double *var = malloc(100000*sizeof(*var));
    /* Code */
    free(var);
}
```

If you are using recursive functions, the stack might become a problem. Let's consider this sum function that sums all natural numbers up to num:

```
unsigned long long sum(unsigned long long num)
{
    if(num == 0) return num;
    return num + sum(n-1);
}
```

A `long long` is typically 8 bytes, so if you use this function for very large num (maybe 100000 or 1000000) you might encounter stack problems.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q1**. I want to know if there is any way to check how much stack memory my code is going to use, performance check of the code(optimization), memory leakage.

You may be able to estimate how much stack space your program will require by analyzing the call graph and the variables declared in each function, but this is not easy for a complex program.  It is much more difficult if any recursion is involved, but one should at least be able to place a rough upper bound.  But the easy way is to *measure* the usage when running on characteristic inputs.

Absolute performance is *extremely* hard for humans to predict.  The best we can usually do reliably is to characterize how performance will scale with problem size.  Comparative performance should always be measured.

As for memory leakage, careful code analysis by humans can usually detect memory leaks, but it is wise to complement that with usage of a runtime memory-usage analysis tool such as Valgrind.  Such tools turn up leaks even in well-analyzed code with distressing frequency.

> **Q2**. if the structure of my code is like,nested functions,
>   [...]
>   because of the function2 call inside a for loop is it going to use
>   more stack memory than using once only?

No.  A function's automatically-allocated resources are released when control leaves that function.  Calling the same function multiple times, whether in a loop or otherwise, does not use more automatic (stack) resources than the most demanding individual call does.

However, when a function *recurses* by directly or indirectly calling itself, it probably does use additional resources proportional to the recursion depth.  I say "probably" because in some cases the compiler may be able to convert the recursion into an iteration within a single function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice not to create large objects on the stack. They should instead be allocated dynamically with `malloc` in C or `new` in C++.

Your program can then recover if the allocation request is refused by the program.

By using the new smart pointers in C++ you can help ensure that all allocations get freed and that no leaks occur, otherwise you just have to "write your code carefully", which is the downside of C programming.